# How do I position a datagridview to the searched text input

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, datagridview, find

Using Windows forms and linq to Sql, I bound a datagridview to Products Table, I added to the form 1 Textbox to input the searched text.
I wonder how to position the datagridview according to the text entered to find a given ProductName.
Here I do not want to filter rows, I only want to reposition datagrid after each character entered, the used code:

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var searchValue = textBox1.Text.Trim().ToUpper();
        var qry = (from p in dc.Products
                   where p.ProductName.ToUpper().StartsWith(searchValue)
                   select p).ToList();
        int itemFound = productBindingSource.Find("ProductName", searchValue);
        productBindingSource.Position = itemFound;
    }
```

The execution of code give the next error: System.NotSupportedException was unhandled at the ligne:

```
int itemFound = productBindingSource.Find("ProductName", searchValue);
```

Any idea please ?

Comment: Is there more than one item in the datagridview that starts with the entered text? That could be causing an exception. Also, does the 'Find' function just look if the column starts with the value provided?

Comment: At Form load event datagrid is filled with the whole content of Products table.

Comment: Right, but does the Find return more than one result?

Comment: @Chris, After Error message nothing changes in the datagridview all Products are shown, because the integer itemFound is not recognized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MSDN documentation for `BindingSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158165.aspx) has the answer:

> The Find method can only be used when the underlying list is an
>   IBindingList with searching implemented. This method simply refers the
>   request to the underlying list's IBindingList.Find method. For
>   example, if the underlying data source is a DataSet, DataTable, or
>   DataView, this method converts propertyName to a PropertyDescriptor
>   and calls the IBindingList.Find method. The behavior of Find, such as
>   the value returned if no matching item is found, depends on the
>   implementation of the method in the underlying list.

When you call this method on a BindingSource whose underlying data source does not implement IBindingList then you see the exception (thrown by the default implementation of [IBindingList.FindCore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132695.aspx):

> System.NotSupportedException: The specified method is not supported.

You don't show what you bind the binding source to but clearly it doesn't implement this method.

Annoyingly, `BindingList<T>` the *recommended* list type to use for your data source does not provide a `FindCore` implementation.

If you are using BindingList you will need to create your own custom type. Here is the code for an absolutely bare bones implementation of a BindingList that supports find:

```
public class FindableBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
{

    public FindableBindingList()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public FindableBindingList(List<T> list)
        : base(list)
    {
    }

    protected override int FindCore(PropertyDescriptor property, object key)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            T item = this[i];
            if (property.GetValue(item).Equals(key))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1; // Not found

    }
}
```

You can do lots with your own implementations of BindingList such as supporting sorting. I've left my answer as just the minimum to support the find method. Search for SortableBindingList if you want to know more.

---

To use this class do something like this:

```
var qry = (from p in dc.Products
               where p.ProductName.ToUpper().StartsWith(searchValue)
               select p).ToList();    

FindableBindingList<YourType> list = new FindableBindingList<YourType>(qry);

dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, please,is there any simplest alternative method to reach the same purpose, or maybe you could explain more how to use your code.

Comment: It all depends - since you don't say what your data source is it is hard to be more exact. There are sources such as DataTable which automatically support Find, but if you can't use one of those (and I usually avoid them) best is to implement your own BindingList. I'll give a more complete example of that in a minute. As an aside, if you are using Linq-to-sql directly to populate your grid you will hit trouble, since this generally gives you read only anonymous types, good for reading, very bad for writing.

Comment: Many many thanks for your efforts. My grid is currently bound to a BindingSource control which is bound to Products class provided by Linq to Sql Model, usually I avoid to use Dataset as datasource, In the past I preferred using Entities Framework, then I noticed that using Linq to Sql give me better performance and less complexity, so I adopted Linq to SQL Classes in my project. Since BindingList is something that I have never known before, I'll take a while to read about it and then return back to try your proposal and give my feed back. Again I am grateful for your helpfulness.

Comment: @AlphaBird that is your problem - your list coming from Linq-to-sql has no implementation of Find. Probably easiest is to take your list from linq and pass it into a find enabled bindinglist.